# Формат фильтрации в Excel

Tags: excel

Всем привет. Есть такое дело. Почему у двух ячеек типа дата по разному реализована фильтрация? Спасибо.

[image: Вот]

Comment: скорее всего некоторые ячейки имеют формат текст, а  некоторые даты ( просто применение формата дата к колонке не всегда превращает текст в дату) можно попробовать `ДАТАЗНАЧ`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина вышеописанного поведения фильтра в том, что часть ячеек имеет формат даты (отображаются в виде иерархического дерева), а часть ячеек - текстовый формат.

[image: Таблица без фильтров]
Для строк столбца `Дата` значения `v` - в столбце `ТипЯчейки`соответствует  любому другому содержанию, кроме текста (`l`) либо пустому значению ячейки (`b`), в столбце `ФорматЯчейки` значение `D1`соответствует формату даты `ДД.ММ.ГГГГ`, а `G`- общему формату.

[image: Таблица с фильтром для столбца 'Дата' (ячейки содержать как числовые, так и текстовые значения)]

Для преобразования `Общего` формата в формат `Даты` используем формулу `=Дата*1` (столбец `Дата*1`).

[image: Таблица с фильтром для столбца 'Дата*1' (ячейки содержат только числовые значения)]

[Описание функции `ЯЧЕЙКА`](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%AF%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%99%D0%9A%D0%90-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%AF%D0%A7%D0%95%D0%99%D0%9A%D0%90-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf)

Comment: >>>Для преобразования Общего формата в формат Даты... - здесь неточность. Если в ячейке формат Общий, то после вставкти даты формат или автоматически преобразуется в Дата, или будем видеть 5-значное число. А вот если дата вставлена как текст, то тут формат ячейки бессилен, он может быть Общий, Текст,  Число, Финансовый... - будем видеть текст

Answer (score 1):

Дата в обычном предствлении *Excel* - число: количество дней, прошедших с  01.01.1900. Например:

```
"31.08.2016"=42613
```

*Excel* так даты и видит - числом. Это нам разрешено (с помощью формата ячейки) видеть так, как нам удобно, но на самом деле в ячейке 5-значное число. Это можно легко проверить. Пишем в А1 дату.

```
=ПОИСК(".";A1)
=ДЛСТР(A1)
```

Первая формула покажет ошибку (в значении нет точки), вторая сообщит, что количество символов =5.
А вот если первая покажет позицию точки и результат второй >5, то можно смело утверждать, что в ячейке даты нет, там текст.

Текст/не текст можно еще проверить так:

```
=ЕЧИСЛО(A1)
=ЕТЕКСТ(A1)
```

Числовые данные, записанные в текстовом представлении, встречаются часто.

Математические операции преобразуют текстовую запись числа в числовую. Сделать это можно с помощью формул, как показал *Roman Sidorin*:

```
=дата*1
=дата+0
=--дата
```

При этом необходимо или оставить доп. столбец в таблице, или заменить полученными данными исходный диапазон.

'---------------

Преобразование можно осуществить с помощью встроенных инструметов.

Копировать пустую ячейку (или ячейку с единицей), выделить нужный диапазон, меню *Правка-Спецвтавка-Сложить* (если копировали единицу, то *Умножить*)-*ОК*. Если копировалась ячейка с форматом, отличным от *Дата*, то поменять формат ячеек на нужный.